# Prevent Google Chrome from tagging the website as deceptive because of an embedded image

Tags: images, google-chrome

Is there a way to prevent Google Chrome from tagging the website because of an embedded image loaded from a deceptive site?

The issue is when someone posts a comment in a blog with an image source from a deceptive site (`<img src="http://deceptivesitegoeshere/malicious.png"/>`, it will display it like that:

[image: Example - Screenshot]

The target is to prevent it from happening, and NOT load the image at all, if found to be from a deceptive site

Comment: It depends on the tech on your site. What kind of site is it? If it is WordPress, this page can be useful https://codex.wordpress.org/Combating_Comment_Spam

Comment: Further to your actual question, which is finding a way to see if Google thinks an image is malicious at time of posting, there is also the issue that if you're not hosting the image yourself, then the website that does could be flagged as malicious at some point in the future. Your best option would be to block hotlinking images unless it's on a site you trust (Imgur for instance).

Comment: _Aside:_ The example you've given is not actually an image-type link, so this particular case could probably be blocked at source with a more strict string/regex validation of the submitted content.

Comment: @MrWhite it was, but the main link was my website (I've to masquerade it), not WordPress, a regular website that loads an image submitted by a comment which caused that specific issue.

Comment: @henrikakselsen I will check this out, although, not using WordPress, but it might help me reviewing the way it works, thanks!